# Yii File type Validation not working

Tags: php, yii

I tried many solution here.But nothing works for me.Please  advice.Here is my code.

My model

Rules

```
public $image_path;
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'check';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('status', 'required'),
            array('status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                //array('image_path', 'unsafe'),
            array('image_path', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png','wrongType'=>'Only image files.','allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'create','on'=>'update'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('c_id, image_path, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Could you add your controller?

Comment: working now...Removed 'on'=>'create','on'=>'update'

Answer (score 0):

```
'on'=>'create','on'=>'update'
```

should be

```
'on'=>'create, update'
```

Comment: Your answer is no different than the comment by Vishal Tech